# Array splice removing wrong item or multiple ones at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I know this is a very basic problem, but my code doesn't want to work correctly. I've tried removing some items from an array stored in this.state but the function just do different things than I expect, sometimes it removes wrong item and recently it started removing more than one item at once, can someone here please review my code and see what's missing?

```
  deleteProduct = async (index) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true, items: [] })
    let { cart } = this.state
    cart.splice(index, 1)
    console.log('deleted this > :', cart.splice(index, 1));
    this.setState({cart:cart})
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
      this.setState({ cart: cart, loading: false })
      this.retrieveCart()
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error: error })
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
```

my data looks like this

```
cart : Array [
  Object {
    "id": 195,
    "price": "69",
    "qty": 1,
  },
  Object {
    "id": 200,
    "price": "69",
    "qty": 1,
  },
  Object {
    "id": 201,
    "price": "110",
    "qty": 1,
  },
]
```

should I just use a different approach like targeting by `id` because that index thing is just not working well

Comment: splice mutates the array probably best to avoid that. I would just filter your data. `this.setState( {cart: cart.filter( item => item.id !== deleteId )})`... In this function currently, you are calling `splice` twice, once to apply the delete and once for a `console.log`. Side effect of this is it removes elements from the array with each call.

Comment: array::splice mutates array in place, so doing once, then again in a console.log will do it twice on the same index. You also are mutating the state object versus a new clean object reference.

Comment: `this.setState({cart:cart.splice(index,1}) ,` did you tried like this ?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin but that would setState the removed item into cart array

Comment: @DrewReese sounds fair I didn't realized that even console.log get executed

Comment: Oh, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is update the code to reference something unique in the data (like the `id` field you have). This isn't required but would be less error prone. I'd use a `filter` here so you don't have array mutation issues between state transitions.

```
this.setState( {cart: cart.filter( item => item.id !== deleteId )}
```

where `deleteId` is the id of the entity the user wishes to delete.

That would look something like this

```
{ cart.map(item =>
    <CartItem
      key={item.id}
      data={item}
      onDelete={this.deleteProduct}
    />
)}
```

assuming `CartItem` calls `this.props.onDelete(this.props.data.id)`

Remember to double check the method you are using to handle data changes like this. [Array::splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutates the array. Currently you are calling `splice` twice in the delete function which will remove elements in both calls.

---

#### Edit:

your function should look something like this

```
deleteProduct = async (deleteId) => {
  this.setState({ loading: true, items: [] })
  const cart = this.state.cart.filter( item => item.id !== deleteId )}
  this.setState({ cart })
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
    this.setState({ loading: false })
    this.retrieveCart()
  } catch (error) {
    this.setState({ error: error, loading: false })
    console.log(error.message)
  }
}
```

Comment: yes I have tried this but it doesnt delete anything

Comment: can you provide more details about what your function looks like that isn't deleting anything with what you've tried?

Comment: it does work but setState is unnecessary I have tried `await AsyncStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart.filter((item) => item.id !== id)))
`

Comment: @usfslk I just edited to include a more full example. Since you are referencing the cart multiple times it would make sense to alias it as a variable that you then reference. If you dont need the `setState` thats great, your code was setting the `cart` update into state so I assumed thats where it was supposed to go :)

Answer (score -1):

yes. ALWAYS and ONLY delete items by item.id. Never using splice.

also you are now deleting multiple items because you added `cart.splice(index, 1))` to your console.log statement. Not good!